# Space between items

Tags: javascript

I've ran into this problem many times over the course of my career and have never given it much thought. My standards have risen to the point where I want a nicer solution. I'll use ES6 to demonstrate, but there is no need to limit answers to the same language. Here's the problem:

Given a list of words, each of which is conditionally printed, but a separator should be printed between each word (ie. before all but the first word).

I often encounter this problem with long chains of if statements where it is solved like so:

```
let something_printed = false;
if (condition1) {
   print(word1); // no space needed here
   something_printed = true;
}
if (condition2) {
   if (something_printed)
      print(' '); // but now a space is necessary
   print(word2);
   something_printed = true;
}
if (condition3) {
   if (something_printed)
      print(' '); // here too
   print(word3);
   something_printed = true;
}
```

Or in a loop:

```
let something_printed = false;
for (let [word, condition] of word_conditions) {
   if (condition)
      if (something_printed)
         print(' ');
   print(word);
   something_printed = true;
}
```

That extra conditional, just to print the separator, bugs me to no end. So I came up with the following (which can be adapted to either of the above examples):

```
let separator = ''; // separator is initially empty
for (let [word, condition] of word_conditions)
   if (condition) {
      print(separator + word);
      separator = ' '; // separator is a space here on out
   }
```

Which is the most succinct solution I have come up with and is what I have been doing for...quite a long time.

So here we have two loops, the first loop catches the first printed word, and the second handles all preceding words:

```
let words = word_conditions.keys();
let conditions = word_conditions.values();
let index;
for (index = 0; index < words.length; index++)
   if (conditions[index]) {
      print(words[index]);
      break;
   }
for (; index < words.length; index++)
   if (conditions[index])
      print(' ' + words[index]);
```

Ignoring the extra indexing, there is no wasted effort in the second loop, which is nice, but this is a more verbose solution, and it takes effort to ignore the extra indexing.

A two-pass approach seem like it might offer some hope, and is nice enough, but is not the most succinct, and pays a price in time and memory due to building an array for printed words:

```
let unconditional_words = [];
for (let [word, condition] of word_conditions)
   if (condition)
      unconditional_words.push(word);
print(unconditional_words.pop());
for (let word of unconditional_words)
   print(' ' + word);
```

Sure, this is quibbling, but I run into this all the time. There has to be a succinct and efficient implementation out there. I haven't explored a more functional approach, but feel like it could contain several better solutions than I've shown above.

**Epilogue**

I probably shouldn't have used Javascript for my examples as the platform I was thinking of doesn't really have the space to build an array and execute a join. (Think old microcontrollers.) However, the vast majority of work I do is not limited in this way. Where I can't spare the space, I'll stick with my third implementation above. On modern tech, join() is applicable, succinct, and efficient. As usual, leveraging someone else's hard work is the best way to go. Thanks Shadow.

So my first example with the ifs can use join() like so:

```
let words = [];
if (condition1)
   words.push(word1);
if (condition2)
   words.push(word2);
if (condition3)
   words.push(word3);
print(words.join(' '));
```

For the second example with the loop:

```
let words = [];
for (let [word, condition] of word_conditions)
   if (condition)
      words.push(word);
print(words.join(' '));
```

Which gives me brief, simple, and understandable solutions. Nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function.
In javascript (and ES6)

```
["First item", "Second item"].join(", ");
```

will return

```
"First item, Second item"
```

Comment: Right. That's probably the best way to approach the problem, use someone else's encapsulated solution. I had a look at a couple of implementations of join(). They were far from succinct, and didn't lead me to any revelations regarding an elegant solution, but they were certainly efficient.

Comment: Any reason you were looking at implementations of join rather than using the inbuilt one? Are you trying to work out how to write your own version rather than to just solve the problem?

Comment: Just to tie up a loose end: @Shadow, since the platform I was targeting at the time was very limited in processing power and space for code, I was curious if any implementations of join() had a clever way of being efficient/succinct. Most were efficient, but not at all succinct. It ended up that I just used join(), which was provided in one of the platforms standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Using join is the built in way to do this in JavaScript.

```js
var words = "Hello this is my sentence";
var comma = words.split(" ").join(", ");
console.log(comma);
```